# The first 10 prime butterflies

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, primes

A *prime butterfly* is a set of three distinct numbers $a,b,c$, such that $a+b$ and $b+c$ are both primes. Can you divide numbers from 1 to 30 into 10 prime butterflies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, observe the facts that:

> Each triplet must be either an **Even-Odd-Odd** triplet, or an **Odd-Even-Even** triplet. Now there are 15 Odd and 15 Even numbers between 1 and 30. Hence, there will be 15 triplets of **Even-Odd-Odd** combination, and another 15 of **Odd-Even-Even** combination. After this, I started putting the first 5 even numbers (one in each triplet) to populate the first 5 triplets.

Proceeding further, the final answer is then:

> [image]

Comment: Maybe fix the headings in the right hand table to "odd even even"

Comment: Sorry..changed now

Comment: Correct! Well done.